# laravel 5.4 image 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, laravel-5.4

I am uploading images to my applications **storage/app/public/avatars** directory. The files are uploading and are there in this folder - i have checked it. And loading the page shows the image as long as i am in my local pc. Then i moved the project to a shared hosting. Since then the images are not loading. From chrome console network tab i can see for the images laravel is throwing 404 error.

Here is what i have tried:

1. On the remote machine i recreated the symbolic link in my **public** folder as **storage** that is pointing to the **storage/app/public** folder.
2. Tried to copy and paste the image src directly into the browser - getting **NotFoundException** in RouteCollection.php
3. Cleared views, cache, config cache

Spent 5 hours trying to figure it out. Works fine on local pc. Just not on the shared hosting.

Desperately seeking help :(

Answer (score 0):

After a bad night sleep of 4 hours i started again and found the problem. Very novice mistake, but can be ver hard to locate.

Here is what it is. I uploaded my laravel project folder to a shared hosting. Say my project name is **myproject**. This folder is at the same level as the **public_html** folder. Then i copied the contents of the **myproject/public** folder to the **public_html** folder.

As you know, you are supposed to create the symbolic link inside your public directory and the link should point to the **storage/app/public** directory (if you are using the *public* disk driver for your file storage). I did create the symbolic link inside the *public* folder, but at the wrong *public* folder. Since i copied the contents of **public** folder to the **public_html** folder, i should have created the symbolic link inside the **public_html** folder, not inside **myproject/public** folder!!

```
----public_html
    ---css
    ---js
    ---(other files etc. etc)
    ---storage  <= this is where the symbolic link should be
----myproject
    ---public
        ---css
        ---js
        ---(other files etc. etc)
        ---storage <= not here!!
```

Very stupid of me.

btw, below is a tutorial of how to transfer a local laravel project to a shared hosting:

[guide to deploy laravel 5 app on shared hosting](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)